# IntPtr and avoiding unsafe code

Tags: c#, .net, intptr

I have an external library that takes an IntPtr.  Is there any safe way to do this...

```
int BytesWritten = 0;
Output.WriteBytes(buffer, new IntPtr(&BytesWritten));
```

...without having to use 'unsafe' code?  I'm not that familiar with IntPtrs, but I'd like to do something like this:

```
fixed int BytesWritten = 0;
Output.WriteBytes(buffer, IntPtr.GetSafeIntPtr(ref BytesWritten));
```

...in such a way that I don't need to compile with /unsafe.

I can't change the WriteBytes function, it's an external function.

It seems like there should be some sort of cast between 'ref int' and IntPtr, but I have not had luck finding it.

Comment: "ref int" produces an IntPtr at run time.  Just change the P/Invoke declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use P/Invoke for your code. It will create the pointer for you automagically. Something like this:

```
[DllImport("yourlib", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool WriteBytes(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    byte [] buffer,
    ref int BytesWritten);
```

*(I added the array as a bonus)*. More info on P/Invoke can be found, with gazillion examples, at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

Each parameter above can take `out`, `in` and `ref`. Out and ref parameters are translated as pointers, where an ref-parameter is two-way.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Tim; I knew it'd be something simple like that.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `Output.WriteBytes` is a `[DllImport]` method. Can you post the declaration?

You should be able to avoid the pointer by declaring the last parameter as `out int` instead of `IntPtr` -- let the P/Invoke marshaller do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that will provide you with a safe IntPtr implementation. It derives from the SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid class, provided by the .NET framework.

```
/// <summary>
/// IntPtr wrapper which can be used as result of
/// Marshal.AllocHGlobal operation.
/// Call Marshal.FreeHGlobal when disposed or finalized.
/// </summary>
class HGlobalSafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates new instance with given IntPtr value
    /// </summary>
    public HGlobalSafeHandle(IntPtr ptr) : base(ptr, true)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates new instance with zero IntPtr
    /// </summary>
    public HGlobalSafeHandle() : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates new instance which allocates unmanaged memory of given size 

  /// Can throw OutOfMemoryException
    /// </summary>
    public HGlobalSafeHandle(int size) :
        base(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size), true)
    {
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Allows to assign IntPtr to HGlobalSafeHandle
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator HGlobalSafeHandle(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        return new HGlobalSafeHandle(ptr);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows to use HGlobalSafeHandle as IntPtr
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator IntPtr(HGlobalSafeHandle h)
    {
        return h.handle;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when object is disposed or finalized.
    /// </summary>
    override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines invalid (null) handle value.
    /// </summary>
    public override bool IsInvalid
    {
        get
        {
            return (handle == IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, if you cannot use `DllImport`. Some background for interested parties: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=543. Note on Netiquette: if you copy / paste from other websites and didn't invent it yourself, make sure to include the link to your source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f74b7c3c-12c4-466b-9754-82e9dea8b83e